# множественный UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Как за один запрос обновить базу? Мой код почему то не работает (

```
$values = '';
foreach($return as $tel){
    //mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE `topic` SET `code`='".$tel['code']."',`simple` = 'true' WHERE `id` = '".$tel['id']."'"); // много много раз
    $values .= "('".$tel['id']."', '".$tel['code']."', 'true'),"; //вместо запроса выше, я хочу собрать все в одну строку...
}
if(!empty($values)){
    //...и за циклом за один запрос обновить базу
    $values=preg_replace("/\,$/", "", $values); //отрезаем последнюю запятую
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE `topic` (`id`, `code`, `simple`) VALUES ".$values."");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

формат запроса `UPDATE` у вас неверный. Надо так:

`UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;`
[Источник](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

А решение Ваше [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/4444092)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за внимание, решил свою проблему следующим образом

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `topic` (`id`, `code`, `simple`) VALUES ".$values." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `code`=VALUES(`code`),`simple`=VALUES(`simple`)");
```